# NullPointerException when adding to an initialized ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to add a new instance of a Block class to an `ArrayList` called blocks.

Here is the code snippet containing the line of error:

```
public class Level1State extends GameState {

    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Block> blocks;

    public Level1State(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        this.blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        player = new Player(30, 30);

        blocks.add(new Block(500, 400));
    }
    ...
}
```

And the Block class is very simple:

```
public class Block extends Rectangle {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int blockSize = 64;

    public Block(int x, int y) {
        setBounds(x,y,blockSize,blockSize);
    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x - (int) GameState.xOffset, y - (int) GameState.yOffset,
                width,
                height);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: and ... where is an NPE thrown? how is that code called? what does setBounds do?

Comment: Could it be that super calls init? Why don't you initialize the list where you declare it?

Comment: @assylias it's not likely for a constructor to call an overridable method.

Comment: @Stultuske It's certainly bad design, but possible.

Comment: which is why I said: not likely. the problem might also be in the setBounds method of the Block constructor. We have no idea where the problem is with the information given.

Comment: Let me guess: your `GameState` class calls `init()` somewhere, which is overridden by your subclass, causing the `blocks` field to be *not yet* initialized. Please post the `GameState` class.

Comment: Yep that was it, super(gsm) was calling init() before the arraylist was initialised, thank you so much